# Check element from 1 column is present in another dataframe with different lengths and names

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 DF with different names and lengths but few elements of 1 column from both DF are common.

I want to check if a particular element is present in the second DF or not and if present copy the elements of that DF in first DF as a new column

**result** column in first DF indicates that **iTOW** of first DF is present in second DF .

DF1:
[image]

DF2:
[image]

I need to check if **iTOW** of first DF is present in second DF : **_iTOW** . If yes then copy that row in the first DF as a new column  . I should then remove the rows from the first DF where result==0 / elements which are not common

Expected DF:
[image]

I tried below code but not able to copy the common elements of second DF to first DF

DF1=DF2.assign(result=source_df['iTOW'].isin(sv_df['_iTOW']).astype(int))

result_df=DF1.loc[DF1['result']==1]

df_common = sv_df.loc[result_df['iTOW'].isin(sv_df['_iTOW'])]

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with a merge (assuming your dataset are a pd.DataFrame), something like this should work

```
DF1.merge(DF2, left_on = 'iTOW' , right_on = '_iTOW', how = 'left')
```